pd.set_option("styler.format.na_rep", "NULL") and pd.options.styler.format.na_rep = "NULL" not working
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.set_option("styler.format.na_rep", "NULL")

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
   ...:                    'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
   ...:                    'weapon': [np.nan, np.nan]})

In [5]: df.to_csv("temp.csv", index=False)

Output of temp.csv
name,mask,weapon
Raphael,red,
Donatello,purple,

The csv last column should be "NULL". The pd.options.styler.format.na_rep = "NULL" does not work neither.
I do not want to set na_rep as a to_csv arg, very much prefer it to be global.
Pandas v2.2.2 (latest), Python 3.10.12 using pyenv binaries.
I tested if maybe na_rep module is broken through to_csv but to_csv works fine replacing np.nan as NULL

pd.options.styler.format.na_rep relates to the style, which is valid for HTML or Excel formatting, not for text/CSV.
For example, in a notebook, df doesn't show the formatting:

But df.style does:

However, although df.style has to_html and to_excel methods, it does not have a to_csv.
One workaround, to have a global setting, could be to create another to_csv method with the default na_ref='NULL':
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def to_csv_null(df, *args, **kwargs):
    return df.to_csv(*args, na_rep='NULL', **kwargs)

PandasObject.to_csv_null = to_csv_null

df.to_csv_null('temp.csv', index=False)

Output:
name,mask,weapon
Raphael,red,NULL
Donatello,purple,NULL

